# PyCharm returns Decode Error but running in command line does not

Tags: python, json, pycharm

I have this code:

```py
import requests

url = 'https://wtrl.racing/assets/js/miscttt170620.php?wtrlid=63'
headers = {'Accept': 'application/json'}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(response.json())
```

If I run it from the CMD I get the right response but if I run it from PyCharm it returns `UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 169648-169649: character maps to <undefined>`
Any ideas why this might be?

Comment: I just ran this in PyCharm, there weren't any issues.

Comment: So did I, worked well.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'm even more confused now I create a new project and it works fine now perhaps my settings were different but at-least it works